# What's causing Express not to pass my variables into the EJS template?

Tags: express, ejs

Express isn't passing my variable into the EJS template.

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24976338/express-angular-ejs-passing-variable-to-template), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37665825/express-ejs-passing-arguments-to-ejs-view), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46646496/passing-variable-from-nodejs-to-ejs-file), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45287000/passing-a-variable-from-routes-js-to-my-ejs-page), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54276174/passing-variable-from-ejs-to-js-script), [and this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37616719/pass-a-variable-from-javascript-to-ejs/37617354). [The most promising one is this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26368693/simple-variable-passed-into-ejs-template-is-undefined)... no dice.

I didn't find something that worked from these.

I've tried removing spaces from `<%- loggedIn %> to no spaces <%-loggedIn%>, making the object in Express simple`res.render('test', {loggedIn: "Simple"})`. I've tried`app.set("view options", { delimiter: "?" });` [like I saw in the EJS/Express wiki](https://github.com/mde/ejs/wiki/Using-EJS-with-Express), no dice.

```js
// /backend/router.js
const app = express();

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("view options", { delimiter: "?" });

app.use("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("test", { loggedIn: "Test" });
});

// /views/test.ejs
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title> </title>
</head>

<body>
  User logged in: <%- loggedIn %>
</body>

</html>
```

I expected "User logged in: Test" to show when I went to localhost:8035. Instead I got `ReferenceError, loggedIn not defined.`

Answer (score 0):

So I did know that when an Express server runs, it caches the routes file. New changes to the routes file in the editor doesn't reflect until restart. I knew this, but when I restarted before, I must've passed in an incorrect variable when I restarted the server. I restarted the server again and the error's no longer there.

But now it just shows `User logged in: <%= loggedIn %>`...